# Do I need to run yum update in fresh centos 7

Tags: centos, yum

Him guys.
Im used to run yum update when begin working on fresh centos servers.
Im working on a dedicated machine for cacti.
Should I install cacti and then run yum update ? or before install cacti or anything ?
 
Regards.
Leandro.

Answer (score 1):

Yum package managers pulls latest packages during installs. So, no just start installation of Cacti. Unlike apt package manager that recommended running updates before installation.